# Maven jar-with-dependencies including 2 of each of my classes

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm using maven to create a self-contained executable jar file with a utility I've written to take a slice of a log file between given date/time stamps & copy this part of the log out to a smaller file. When I do

```
mvn install
```

maven creates 2 jar files, LogCopy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar & LogCopy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar. It's weird that it creates the two archives, but weirder yet, and a cause of concern for me, is that in the larger .jar there seems to be 2 of every class I've written.

My POM.xml uses the maven-assembly plugin thus:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>create-my-bundle</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.myproject.subproject.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? I'm at a loss - Google doesn't seem to have much on it & I can't find anything much on it in O'Reilly's "Maven: The Definitive Guide". Why is it putting 2 of each class into the .jar, and why does it do a .jar without dependencies as well as the one with?

Answer (score 1):

Two jar files are generated because LogCopy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is created by a "normal" maven build. You've just added plugin that additionally (as a side task) creates LogCopy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar archieve. The maven-assembly-plugin does not disable "normal" build it just executes extra task during package phase.

Comment: Ah, fair enough - so I can just safely ignore that one then. Any idea why there's 2 of each of my classes in there?

Comment: @Matt Moran - No, it is odd for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-399

I'm not sure what version of Maven you are using, but one of the comments there indicates you can use the following XML...

```
<archiverConfig><duplicateBehavior>skip</duplicateBehavior></archiverConfig>
```

If you browse through that JIRA, you can see quite a few bugs related to that issue.

Comment: OK - tried that, result seems to be the same. I'll have a bit more of a poke about in that JIRA though.

Answer (score 1):

Just downloaded 2.2-beta-5 of the maven assembly plugin.The issue of .class duplicates in the jar file is fixed in that version. Though I still wonder how the same file name could be packed into the same location in a jar.

Answer (score -1):

In version 2.2 all looks ok, so temporary you can add:

```
<version>2.2</version>
```